# How to use Eclipse to trace into functionality within a .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been through about a dozen or so tutorials on the IDE, and so far, no luck.  I'm hoping someone here can shed some light... The solution to this problem should be relatively straight forward. (knock knock)

1. I have been provided .jar files from another party (include the source code)
2. Some code in one of the .jar files breaks under certain conditions  (go figure!)
3. I can set up the system variables (sadly this is being performed in windbloze) and can run the execution of code that relies on the functionality within that said .jar file from the command line with no problems.
4. Issues is that I need to be able to set up the Eclipse IDE to 'hook' into the .jar files so that I can replicate the command-line functionality but trace into it with the IDE's debugger.
5. So, question is basically two-fold, 1) is this possible in Eclipse (V.4.3.2) and 2) how can a jar files be 'hooked' into a project that simply needs to execute a command line.

Example of the working command-line code:

C:\Work\tmp> set MY_DIR=C:/Work/tmp

C:\Work\tmp> set CLASS_VARS=%MY_DIR%/my_jar1.jar

C:\Work\tmp> java -cp %CLASS_VARS% -DmyTest.properties=%MY_DIR%/myTest.properties com.theirApp.RemoteExec --params....yada yada"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David's answer does not address your problem. I believe you are trying to debug executable jars... if you have corresponding source on eclipse that is exactly in sync with the .`jar` that you are using, you can use the Remote Debugging feature of the jvm.

Execute your jar with one of the following commands (specifying main class/classpath if you do not have a manifest, of course)

**Pre Java 1.5:**

`java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=[PortNumberHere] -jar [YourJarHere]`

**Java 1.5+:**

`java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=[PortNumberHere] -jar [YourJarHere]`

In Eclipse, create a debug configuration for a `Remote Java Application`. Ensure that the port number is the one that your app is listening on, that you are using the `Socket Connect` option, and that you have the correct project selected. Then, go to the source tab and add all of your source directories that you would like to debug.

If done correctly the debugging should behave exactly as if you were debugging the jar in-house, except it being remote and all.

Comment: Thank you.  I think that is exactly what I need to do.  We'll give it a shot, and your input is GREATLY appreciated.   We'll post if that works.  Cheers & bug free code!

Comment: So, the remote java application approach hasn't seemed to work, so in lieu of that I've been trying to configure the IDE's project configuration tool to mimic the command line that works.

There should be a way to exactly replicate the 3 commands listed in my initial post, correct?

Since I have no 'code' of my own, I simply want to execute the java command and 'trace' into those .jar files.  I have no specific port that I'm connecting to, just and IP address for the remote execution call, so the socket connection option for the remote debug really isn't the solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @KokAddict now you're confusing me. The port number that you specify can be any random port, essentially the socket is a communication channel that links your Eclipse jdwp debugger with your remote jar, allowing for breakpoints and runtime diagnostics to be communicated back and forth. There is no way to debug a jar file if you do not have  at LEAST the source code for that jar. If obtaining the source code is not an option, you can attempt to use a decompiler that reverse engineers the java code from the .class bytecode, but there is a high likelihood that the line numbers will not match up.

Comment: @KokAddict there is absolutely no point in automating those batch commands, Eclipse has project settings for the class path. If you need to simulate a set of arguments Eclipse also has settings for that. You do realize that all your batch commands are doing are merely creating some shell environment variables that are then fed into the same old `java` command, specifying classpath and properties? It seems like you might want to read on the `java` command, you really aren't doing anything that my answer doesn't allow for, besides not having access to the jar source

Comment: Thanks for the updates, your input and the follow-up.  Yes, my functioning command-line code is just setting paths and variables for the java command execution; no worries there.

And I DO HAVE the .jar files as well as the code that I'm trying to debug.

I'm just trying to determine how to essentially use/setup the IDE to hook into the .jar file execution so it can be traced.  I apologize I haven't been able to expressly note that in my questions thus far

I'm sure there's a way to do the "java -cp XXX -DYYY command params" execution through the IDE so it tracable, just not sure how

Comment: @KokAddict no, there is NOT a way to do that quoted command from within eclipse and debug at the same time and even if there was, it would probably be extremely convoluted. The way to do it is to launch your jar with the remote debugging option I detail in this answer (you can append your class path arguments, main class argument, -D jvm environment arguments, parameters, and whatever else you fancy as well) and then you can hook your eclipse debugger into the jar, which is hosting a socket waiting for your debugger to connect to.